# Deploy php app on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to deploy my app on Digital ocean droplet Ubuntu 16.04.

When I'm accessing to the website (example.com) it's showing the content of the index.php

virtual host file look as below:

```
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory /var/www/myproject>
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
  </Directory>
```

Any idea how this fix this issue ?

Comment: if you see the content of the file "<?php $foo = 'bar'; " it means php is not working correctly.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04